# Multiple user input prints particular style

Tags: python

I simply would now like to input multiple groups of integers to be counted individually. 
It would flow something like this.

first get the user input all at one time.

Enter numbers 1... 2,4,23,45,57

Enter numbers 2... 9,23,45,47,33

Enter numbers 3... 2,41,23,45,55

then the out come is printed out all at once.

sequence for numbers 1... 2,0,1,0,1,1

sequence for numbers 2... 1,0,1,1,2,0

sequence for numbers 3... 1,0,1,0,2,1

here's my code.

```
import collections 

the_input1 = raw_input("Enter numbers 1... ")
the_input2 = raw_input("Enter numbers 2... ")
the_input3 = raw_input("Enter numbers 3... ")

the_list1 = [int(x) for x in the_input1.strip("[]").split(",")]
the_list2 = [int(x) for x in the_input2.strip("[]").split(",")]
the_list3 = [int(x) for x in the_input3.strip("[]").split(",")]

group_counter = collections.Counter(x//10 for x in the_list1)
group_counter = collections.Counter(x//10 for x in the_list2)
group_counter = collections.Counter(x//10 for x in the_list3)

bin_range = range (6) 

for bin_tens in bin_range: 
    print "There were {} in {} to {}".format(group_counter[bin_tens], bin_tens*10, bin_tens*10+9)
```

Any response would be greatly appreciated.. Thank you..

Comment: I have no idea how or why you're turning one number set into the other.

Comment: First of all, you're overwriting `group_counter` a few times, which looks suspect.  It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want the frequency of the numbers in the ranges 0-9, 10-19,..., 50-59 seperately for your 3 inputs. I refactored your program to achieve this:

```
import collections 

the_inputs = []
for i in range(3):
    the_inputs.append(raw_input("Enter numbers {}... ".format(i+1)))

the_lists = []
for the_input in the_inputs:
    the_lists.append([int(x)//10 for x in the_input.strip("[]").split(",")])

for i, the_list in enumerate(the_lists):
    print "Input {}".format(i+1)
    group_counter = collections.Counter(the_list)
    bin_range = range (6) 
    for bin_tens in bin_range: 
        print "There were {} in {} to {}".format(group_counter[bin_tens], bin_tens*10, bin_tens*10+9)
```

I get the expected output with your given input.

Comment: SOrry for the suspicion but im very new to python.  Never the less your code does the job.  Thank you.